# Android, libphonenumber, frequent NPE when loading metadata

Tags: android, phone-number, libphonenumber

I'm developing and supporting an android application massively using google's libphonenumber library.

The application sends crash reports to our server and there are quite many of them telling about NPE in DataInputStream.readToBuff method called eventually from PhoneNumberUtil.loadMetadataForRegionFromFile method.

Also, there are noticeable amount of reports on failed verification of META-INF/CERT.SF, of course, in connection with loading of the library metadata. Thus, I suppose that the problem source is packaging of the meta data into the source tree and using the ClassLoader to access them.

Does anybody experiencing the same issues and interested to find an appropriate solution? Or may be there is known reliable one?

This time I'm going to patch the library so as it will load the metadata, e.g. from the project assets or from a server to the projects database. Would like any cooperation in the matter.

Answer (score 0):

We've had a similar issue in accessing the phone number meta data from the package com.google.i18n.phonenumbers.data .

After copying the needed files again to our project in the same package I haven't seen a NullPointerException anymore.